# Does EKS bill include the costs for control-plane (master) nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-eks

EKS costs $0.10 / hr + you pay for the worker nodes (EC2 + storage + data transfer). But EKS itself runs master nodes. So the question is: does $0.10 covers the costs of master nodes? If not, then how can I control the node type used for master nodes?

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUL8TnMONfRK-br8q8gcq1AA/eks-pricing-for-three-master-nodes looks like $0.10 covers the master nodes, but I'm still not sure

Comment: Best send an email to AWS billing support, it's free to contact them if it's a billing question.